# UIApplication openURL: Open Just iTunes App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, itunes

How can I open up just the iTunes app. Not any subpages in the app like a song or video but just the app. Right now I am using: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://music"]];` but sometimes this gives an error saying invalid hostname: music. When I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://"]];` I get bad URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the following and it seems to be working fine

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://?action=music"]];
```

Comment: No worries, clad it helped you